# Sorting list of names and assigning marks

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code that allows me to input 2N lines consisting of names followed by grades and outputs them sorted alphabetically with the name and each corresponding grade side by side.

An example of the input would be

```
3
Betty
60
Cathy
50
Annie
40
```

And the output would be:

```
Annie : 40
Betty : 60
Cathy : 50
```

This is what I have so far:

```
N = int(input())
for i in range (2*N):
    m = input()
    marks_list = m.split()
```

I have tried a few different methods to try and sort the list but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Have you trying solving it on paper, writing some pseudocode, something like that?

Comment: Please work through more tutorials to learn the basic techniques.  Learn basic diagnostic techniques, such as inserting a `print` statement to display your critical variable values.  This code does not yet properly gather the input, so sorting is certainly *not* going to work.

Comment: I have, I tried a few different things and none of them worked:

I used:

sorted_marks_list = sorted(marks_list)
print(sorted_marks_list)

I'm going to try to use a function that takes into account the fact that I have numerical strings as well.

Comment: I'm sure you get much more answers if you post just a few of the things, that you tried, even if they didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I figured out another way to do it using a dictionary and this is the code that I came up with.

```
N = int(input())
markslist = {}

for i in range(N)
    name = input
    mark = int(input())

    markslist[name]=mark

for name, mark in sorted(markslist.items())
    print(name, ":", mark)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to try on papers first before getting your hands into code. I advise you do that before reading my answer.

First of all, we read N, which is the number of -let's assume- students. For each one of them we are going to take two inputs: the name and mark. So you can run a loop only N times not 2*N, and in each iteration you take two inputs.

Second, lists and tuples will help you a lot, creating a list of tuples to be sorted later will significantly reduce work. So for each student we will create a tuple(name, mark) and insert that tuple in a list.

Third, finally after getting the input, we just need to sort. There is a pretty handy function in python that does the sorting part for you, but I really ***recommend*** you do the sorting step yourself if you do not know how it works from the inside. I mean implement any sorting algorithm at least.

Here is the solution:

```
N = int(input())
# list
li = []
for i in range (N):
   # taking two inputs
   name = input()
   mark = input()
   # creating a tuple and appending to list
   li.append((name, mark))

# sorting by name, the first element in the tuple, 
# that's why there is tp[0]
sortedbyname = sorted(li, key=lambda tp: tp[0])

# printing results
for i in range(N):
   print(f"{sortedbyname[i][0]}: {sortedbyname[i][1]}")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi this does help tremendously. I initially looked up ways to sort a list containing different types of keys and this was what I came up with at first

sorted_marks_list = sorted(marks_list, key= lambda m: m[0])

print(sorted_marks_list)

But it would only print the number and not the name. And I even tried to create a dictionary but that just seemed to confuse the program even more.

Comment: @NokuthabaMoyo glad to help. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample example of ascending name alphabetically with randomly generated names and marks of the students

```
import string 
import random 

li = []
print("")
N = int(input("Enter The Number of Students in the class : "))
print("")
def getRandomList():

    for i in range (N):
        newName = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase,k=3))
        name=str(newName)
        mark = random.randint(0, 100) 
        li.append((name, mark))
        sortedbyname = sorted(li, key=lambda tp: tp[0])

    print("Print the names and their marks sorted by name alphabetically")
    print("")
    print('{:5s} {:15s}  ' .format('Name','Marks'))
    print("")
    for i in range(N):
        print(f"{sortedbyname[i][0]}     {sortedbyname[i][1]}")
    print("")
    

getRandomList()
```

Output for a sample random list is shown below

```
Enter The Number of Students in the class: 10

Print the names and their marks sorted by name alphabetically

Name  Marks

CFN     90
DIL     96
MIA     26
OIG     35
SNH     11
TBU     45
THW     3
VIR     26
XYS     62
YIU     9
```